# differentiate between multiple properties files

Tags: java, properties

My application has different customers (around 20) , every customer has their own `*.properties` file with the connection settings, property parameters are the same.

Currently I have for every customer an own method to read the properties and store it in `Customer`. With 20 Customers, its inflated. I'm searching now for a better solution.

```
    private final static Customer get_CustomerXXXX() {

        final Properties p = new Properties();

            p.load(S.class.getResourceAsStream("customerXXX.properties"));
            return new Customer (p.getProperty("PARAM1", p.getProperty("PARAM2", p.getProperty("PARAM3")
    }

    if(SPECIFIC_CUSTOMER.XXXX) {
        customerSettings = get_CustomerXXXX();

    } else if(SPECIFIC_CUSTOMER.BBBB) {
        customerSettings = get_CustomerBBBB();
    }
```

Comment: *Please* pay attention when formatting code. It's all over the place at the moment. Bear in mind that Stack Overflow's goal it to be a repository of high quality questions and answers - unreadable code detracts from that goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomerTest {
    private String identifier;

    public CustomerTest(String identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public Properties getProerties() {
    Properties p = null;
    try {
            p = new Properties();
            p.load(CustomerTest.class.getResourceAsStream("customer" + identifier + ".properties"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

this would be the way you suggested in the comments @OP.

Answer (score 0):

> property parameters are the same

if you are sure that in future also i'll be same. then you can read the property file first time only. From next time on wards, use values loaded from previous property file.

You can combine Singleton and Factory Method design patterns here.

You should have a method such as following:

```
private final static Properties getProperties(String idetifier)
{
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(S.class.getResourceAsStream("customer"+idetifier+".properties"));
    return p;
}
```

Comment: but connection settings some to be different

Comment: it is only connection setting that are different, then only put connection settings in customer specific files. Move common value to separate file.

Comment: `every customer has their own *.properties file with the connection settings, property parameter names are the same` thats what he said. as i understand it, only the parameter name (key) is not different, but the value is. meaning every porperties file has like param1=xxx and param2=yyy. xxx and yyy can change but param1 and param2 always exist with that name. i might be wrong, but that has op to tell us

Comment: Then you have to load all the properties in separate object for each customer. but if only one customer is allowed to use the application at one time, then previous loaded values can be disposed.

Comment: @Aelop you are rught, only the parameter names are the same.

Comment: but we don't know if only 1 customer is allowed at a time

Comment: this would inflate as well since you have like 20 customers. why not simply go for the `S.class.getResourceAsStream("customer"+idetfier+".properties")` if you already pass it to the method (look at my answer)?

Comment: @Aelop Agreed!!

Comment: Is it also a proper way, when I initialize the Customer Identifier in the Customer Constructor ? and using in the class Customer a static method getProperties(), without any parameters?

Comment: That identifier is actually properties identifier, and any customer object can use that. So initializing Customer with identifier seems wrong. you should initialize customer with required values only.

Comment: in your example yes, but i think that he means that the identifier also identifies the customer and not just the properties file

Comment: @Aelop he is creating Customer using properties loaded, not with identifier.